# ¿Como dividir un Jpanel en dos mitades?

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica, jframe

Que tal tengo el siguiente problema tengo un JFrame donde tengo que agregar un panel central y a ese panel central lo tengo que dividir en dos paneles (partirlo en dos partes iguales) lo que estoy haciendo es al panel central le di un atributo de cental.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); entonces en armado puse central.add(panel1,BorderLayout.WEST); y central.add(panel2,BorderLayout.EAST); y pone a los dos paneles en el lado izquierdo y derecho pero solo aparecen una pequeñas lineas intente darle un tamaño a panel1 y panel2 pero no funciona ¡como lo resuelvo?

tengo este código:

p

```
ublic class Paneles {

//Interfaz grafica de usuario
    private JFrame ventana;
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JPanel panel2;
    private JPanel central;

    public Paneles() {

        ventana = new JFrame();
        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel2 = new JPanel();
        central = new JPanel();
        this.atributos();
        this.armado();
        this.lanazar_IGU();
    }

    public void atributos() {
        ventana.setSize(400, 200);
        ventana.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        central.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        ventana.setResizable(true);

    }

    public void armado() {
       ventana.add(central,BorderLayout.CENTER);
       central.add(panel1,BorderLayout.WEST);
       central.add(panel2,BorderLayout.EAST);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complemento la respuesta de @Emmanuel con algo de codigo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    JFrame window = new JFrame("my homework");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setBounds(0,0,400,400);
    window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel centralPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();


    centralPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));

    rightPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
    leftPanel.setBackground(Color.red);

    centralPanel.add(rightPanel);
    centralPanel.add(leftPanel);

    window.add(centralPanel);
    window.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la observación si me falto agregar codigo

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos pero logre resolverlo se arreglaba con algo tan sencillo como un gridLayout donde al panel central le di una distribución gridLayout(1,2); después en el armado puse central.add(panel1); central.add(panel2);